# is filter is replaceable of query in mongo queries using c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

I'm new to mongo in c#

I found tow ways to find documents based on search critiria:

the first using filter:

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("restaurants");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("address.zipcode", "10075");
var result = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

The second using query:

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> books;
var query = Query.EQ("author", "Kurt Vonnegut");
foreach (BsonDocument book in books.Find(query)) {
    // do something with book
}
```

What's the best way to find documents based to what MongoDB recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know query builders (like your second example  using `Query.EQ`) belong to old versions of C# drivers (1.X) (see [Query](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.11/) class). Also I suggest you to see *Builder* section in this [link](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/) that confirm query builders is the old way to consult data.

After the release of the 2.0 version of the .NET driver, a lot of changes were made, including the way of consult the data (you can read more about that in this [link](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/)). If you are using the last C# driver version you should use your first approach.

Comment: Yes, that is  what I was asking., The first approach is recommended. thanks for the  answer and for the link.

Answer (score 0):

The first way you mentioned is quite fine. You might want to incorporate using a mongo cursor as well to allow you to iterate through results

```
    var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("restaurants");
    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("address.zipcode", "10075");
    using(var _cursor = await collection.Find(filter).ToCursorAsync())
    {
        while(await _cursor.MoveNextAsync())
        {
            foreach(var _document in _cursor.Current) //gets current document
            {
                //you can do things like get the _id of the document
                var _id = _document["_id"];
            }
        }
    }
```